# Compile time optimization of simple math expressions in C++

Tags: c++, compile-time-constant, numeric-limits

I have a piece of code which basically adds some constant number to all elements of an array

```
Matrix a.array() += 32768; //Bad due to hard coded literal
```

Matrix has scalar type of `unsigned short int`.
Some other options I am exploring are as following:

```
Matrix a.array() += std::numeric_limits<Matrix::Scalar>::max()/2 + 1;
```

and

```
Matrix a.array() += (std::numeric_limits<Matrix::Scalar>::max() >> 1) + 1;
```

The second solution looks most readable to me, but do I pay a penalty compared to the 1st option. Does any standard compiler will precompute this during compile time?

I am currently using gcc 4.6.3, but I am not using C++11 due to some dependencies on older code.

**Update:**

From my limited knowledge of the assembly output, I'll say that the compiler is not optimizing it. The story is same even with -std=c++0x flag.

Here are the assembly outputs:

[Using Method 2 with -std=c++0x flag](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9907788)

[Hardcoded Literal](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9907873) (See line 26)

**Update2**

Using -O2 flags produces identical assembly files irrespective of -std=c++0x flag use or not.

**Conclusion**

Since optimization flags like -O2 does the correct job, Method2 probably is the best practice. Also since these codes are now part of a class member methods, I ended up using a private const variable intialized to `std::numeric_limits<MyMatrix::Scalar>::max()/2 + 1`

Comment: One way to know for sure is to look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: The function is marked `constexpr`, so it must be in C++11.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I checked the assembly. Its not.

Comment: Try using the C macro: `Matrix a.array() += (USHRT_MAX >> 1)+1;`

Comment: Did you use -O2 or similar?

Comment: @TonyD Ooops. I forgot those flags for producing the assembly.

Answer (score 1):

Previously you could declare something as `const` and someone could override it's `const`ness so the compiler might not have optimised your code. With C++11 you can declare something `constexpr` which says, "Yes really, this is a constant, and you can use it at compile time". What this means is that any `constexpr` functions with `constexpr` arguments can be evaluated at compile time.

So what does this mean in your particular case? If you're using C++11 (which I highly recommend) then as the function `std::numeric_limits<unsigned short int>::max()` is declared as a `constexpr` it will be optimised out at compile time.

Enabling c++11 is usually as simple as setting a compiler flag.

Comment: Nice. But is there a C++99 solution. Since I have some dependencies which does not like the C++11 flag

Comment: @iNFINITEi, I'm not sure it's possible with templates like you're doing without `constexpr`. There are of course things like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/climits which will be optimised away. The calculation itself is pretty cheap, I wouldn't worry about it, especially if you're doing things with matrices, the cost will be negligable.

Comment: Ya I was probably doing premature optimization. Meanwhile updated the question with a conclusion because of the -O2 flags suggested by Tony